# How to know if a zero bytes video was uploaded to a gcp bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

As the title says, I need to fetch the size of the video / object I just uploaded to the bucket.

Every few seconds, an object is uploaded to my bucket which is of the form, `{id}/video1.mp4`.

I want to make use of google cloud storage [triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)  which would alert me if a 0 byte video was added. Can someone pls suggest me how to access the size of the added object.

Comment: The event delivered to a storage trigger has metadata describing the file.  If you read through the documentation carefully, you should be able to see how this works for the language of your choice.

Comment: But you can't have an event on only the 0 byte video file. You will have event on each file, and, as @DougStevenson said, you have to check the file size in metadata.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm confused. Are you saying that no event will be triggered for a zero-sized file that gets successfully uploaded?

Comment: No, it's simply my English which is bad.  I would like to say that there is no filter possible. You can't receive event only for some type of file. You receive event on each file, and you have to look into metadata to determine if the file is a 0 byte or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Farhan,

Assuming you know the basics of cloud functions. You can create a cloud function trigger that runs a script every-time you create/finalize an object in a selected bucket. 
The link you posted contains the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) and the following python script attached.

```
def hello_gcs_generic(data, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
       This generic function logs relevant data when a file is changed.

    Args:
        data (dict): The Cloud Functions event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    Returns:
        None; the output is written to Stackdriver Logging
    """

    print('Event ID: {}'.format(context.event_id))
    print('Event type: {}'.format(context.event_type))
    print('Bucket: {}'.format(data['bucket']))
    print('File: {}'.format(data['name']))
    print('Metageneration: {}'.format(data['metageneration']))
    print('Created: {}'.format(data['timeCreated']))
    print('Updated: {}'.format(data['updated']))
```

In this example, we see data has multiple items such as name, timeCreated ect. 
What this example doesn't show however is that data has another item, SIZE! 
listed as `data['size']`

So now we have a cloud function that gets the filename, and file size of whatever is uploaded when it's uploaded!. all we have to do now is create an if statement to do "something" if the file size is = 0. It will look something like this in python. (apologies for syntax issues, but this is the jist of it)

```
def hello_gcs_generic(data, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
       This generic function logs relevant data when a file is changed.

    Args:
        data (dict): The Cloud Functions event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    Returns:
        None; the output is written to Stackdriver Logging
    """
    print('File: {}'.format(data['name']))
    print('Size: {}'.format(data['size']))

    size = data['size']

    if size == 0: 
        print("its 0!")
    else:
        print("its not 0!")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: NOTE: I ran the above script in my own ENV and was successful!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I got it working in Nodejs. And yes, initially i thought the size attribute is not present, but when I printed all the attributes, I found it was there.